# Disabling SessionStateModule

Tags: asp.net, session, httpmodule

Recently I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23306/10-ASP-NET-Performance-and-Scalability-Secrets) and decided to remove unnecessary `httpModules`.

I disabled `SessionStateModule`:

```
<httpModules>
    ...
    <remove name="Session" />
    ...
</httpModules>
```

but I still can use `Session` object all the same. Why? Perhaps, I didn't understand correctly the recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

What say there is to remove unnecessary modules - **if you use the Session DO NOT remove it**!

In general say that is better to fully remove the modules than just disabled them on web.config because the disables flag is called too many times, but if you totally remove you avoid this extra call.

Comment: 1) no, i don't need Session in the project - i just tried to write there smth and read it. and i don't understand why i was able to do that(= 2) as i understand i've just disabled this module, but how can i 'fully remove' it? (is it being done on iis lvl?)

Comment: If you do not use session then add this line. With this line you do not disabled but you remove the module from the pipeline for this project. Actually what happends here is that there is a global setup that say what to load, and adding this line you remove this module from the global setup only for this site start... I do not know if I make you understand it now, if not tell me what else you do not understand.

Comment: i understand relations between machine.config and web.config - i don't understand why Session works when i removed this module from the pipeline of the site.

Comment: @donRumatta The machine.config is loaded, and then web.config overwrite the parameters that first readed on machine.web - If you remove the session then IS NOT WORKING !. The machine.config is a global first start initialization for all, and then web.config is extra settings for every program.